# How do I get the string value in this string interpolation

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to get this code to output:

```
'Mary has a pet called Satan.'
```

But what I get is:

```
'Mary has a pet called #<Cat:0x00000002784c20>'
```

Code Below:

```
class Person
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @pet = nil
        @hobbies = []
    end

    def describe()
        puts "This persons name is #{@name}."
        puts "#{@name}'s hobbies are:"

        @hobbies.map { |hobby| puts hobby }

        if @pet == nil
            puts "#{@name} has not got any pets."
        else
            puts "#{@name} has a pet called #{@pet}"
        end
    end

    attr_accessor :pet, :hobbies
end
class Cat < Animal

def initialize(name)
    @name = name
end
end


satan = Cat.new("Satan")
mary = Person.new("Mary")
mary.pet = satan

mary.describe
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Please share your Cat class as well.

Comment: Are you getting `Mary has a pet called #<Cat:0xsome_hex>`?

Comment: How is this question related to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @SujanAdiga yup this is exactly what I'm getting.

Comment: @FreddieCodes then try `"#{@name} has a pet called #{@pet.name}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `describe()` function, you are calling the object `Cat` without specifing the name.

But if you call `#{pet.name}` it will throw:

```
<undefined method `name' for #<Cat:0x0055d750a1a450 @name="Satan">
```

You have to allow the access to the variable `name` in the `Cat` class first with [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

```
class Cat < Animal
  attr_accessor :name # First allow access

end


class Person
  def describe()
     puts "#{@name} has a pet called #{@pet.name}" # Then call the pet's name!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked a treat and now I understand better how and when to use attr_accessor .

Comment: Glad it helps you out! Check out for @Gerry solution to see `attr_reader`, it is not a bad idea. Either way, try to read documentation about them both. Please do not forget to tick this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer is better, nicely explained.